# Being transcendental and contingency of constants of nature

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, physics, probability

Given an arbitrarily chosen constant of nature (say, the speed of light *c*), we can confidently say that the fact that it is equal to 299 792 458 meters per second is a contingent fact about our universe (in other words, it is logically possible for *c* to equal some other value). In fact, it is logically possible for any constant to be equal to *any* positive real number other than the one it has in the actual world.

Let's also take into consideration the fact from mathematics that if you chose a random positive real number, the probability of choosing an algebraic number is exactly zero.

Given these two premises, does it follow that all of the nature's constants are not algebraic, i.e. transcendental (and hence irrational)?

**EDIT:** To make things more robust, let's make the following assumption: A Theory of Everything exists, and we are talking about it, it only and *its* constants.

**NOTE:** Constants varying with time don't change the essence of the question - if the constant is changing with time, then my question is about its value at a particular point *t* in time.

Comment: The fine-tuning argument suggests that the tunable constants in the Standard Model have only got a narrow range of variation if a universe capable of bearing life is to emerge.

Comment: @MoziburUllah my question is not about constants that are fit for life to emerge, but about all the possible values any given constant can take on (regardless if the resulting universe is lifeless or not).

Comment: Constants of nature are measured: thus they are rational. The only way to assert that a number is irrational is through a mathematical proof (like for the square root of 2 and *e*).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am adhering to a form of realism here, meaning that constants of nature have _some specific value_ regardless of our measuring them, meaning they can in fact be irrational.

Comment: See [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light): "The speed of light in vacuum, commonly denoted c, is a universal physical constant important in many areas of physics. Its exact value is 299,792,458 metres per second (approximately 3.00×108 m/s, or 300,000 km/s (186,000 mi/s)). It is exact because the unit of length, the metre, is defined from this constant and the international standard for time."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am talking about the constants of nature, and you are talking about the definition of a meter.

Comment: Although we would never know what they exactly are, we can assume the "constants" of nature (should there be any) are irrational numbers (even transcendental numbers).  However, these constants may vary with time.  Search "variable speed of light" or "variable gravitational constant" for theories that do not require constants to be constant.  It is also logically possible that the theories we have created using constants only approximate reality.  Not only may the constants vary given correct theories, there may not be any constants.

Comment: @FrankHubeny you are indeed making valid points, I would love to hear a full answer from you. If the constants are variable, this doesn't change the question at all - the question will then be about the value of the constant at any given point _t_ in time. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

First, the fine-tuning argument suggests that the tunable constants in the Standard Model have only got a narrow range of variation if a universe capable of bearing life is to emerge. So they can't quite be anything.

Second,  before we can find out whether a number is irrational we must measure it to infinite accuracy. In mathematics, this is a given. In physics, this is not so. A measurement with infinite precision needs to be carried out.

Thus, given the limits on accuracy given by physical measuring instruments and the actual indeterminacy at the Planck scale it seems to me that to ask whether physical constants are rational or irrational is not a physically meaningful question.

Still, it's an interesting question.

Comment: _"So they can't quite be anything."_ - it is logically possible for them to be anything. _"A measurement with infinite precision needs to be carried out."_ - I am not concerned with measuring these constants in the real world, I am talking about their exact values in a platonic sense. About your second to last paragraph - according to the mainstream physics, space is continuous, not discrete. Also, what the Planck scale really represents is debatable

Comment: @Alex Adamov: What makes you think that they can be so concieved? It's more likely given what physics has found out after the that advent of QM that even platonically speaking, that physical numbers do not have infinite precision.

Comment: Because there is no logical contradiction in conceiving them so. Elaborate on the QM bit, because I do not agree with you on that either.

Comment: @Alex Adamov: I think we'll have to agree on our disagreements. I don't happen to think mere logical coherence is sufficient in physics. Basically, the mathematical continuum is an approximation to the actual physical continuum, and how to conceptualise this is already a difficult problem.

Comment: _"I don't happen to think mere logical coherence is sufficient in physics."_ -
 we are doing philosophy, not physics. About the continuum thing: and yet physicists use the mathematical continuum to model the physical continuum, and so far this has been successful. On the contrary, viewing space as discrete introduces many problems physics can't deal with.

Comment: @Alex Adamov: yeah, sure - I'm not sure why you feel philosophy ought to be reduced to logic, that merely waving the logical wand makes things philosophical. Kant would say, judgement is far more important. Well, that's no surprise since these are difficult questions without much guidance from experiment since we're talking about the level of structure round about the Planck scale.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is a strong opinion that the mathematical continuum is inadequate here, for example, there's an ongoing programme by Rafael Sorkin to reconceptualise space discretely and dynamically - the causal sets programme.

Comment: If you asked all of the physicists in the world whether they think space is continuous (in the mathematical sense of the word) or not, I bet 90% of them would say it is.

Comment: @Alex Adamov: I can't say a vox populi is really relevant. I'd rather go by what the ongoing current research programmes say: on that basis, most say that the usual continuum description is suspect. Philosophically it's suspect too, what physical presence can a mere point actually have? At most it represents position and not what is. In some sense, mereology which argues for parthood relationship has merit, rather than the set theory with its elements that the real number line is based upon.

Comment: Mereology protests against the conceptualisation of everything as bags of points. On this, Category Theory, another foundational programme in mathematics concurs. It's says that points can be very different and are not simply mere points.

Comment: By the way, I up voted your question. Whilst I've already said, I don't agree with the premises of the question, I think it is an interesting one.

Comment: @AlexAdamov while this might be a question about Philosophy, not Physics, it seems like the relevant “coherence constraints” for discussion of “constants of nature” would be the limits of nomological possibility — roughly, what is possible given the (actual) laws of nature. Otherwise you have metaphysical possibility — which would allow for possibilities without anything like our laws of nature — or logical possibility, which allows anything which isn’t inconsistent (within some suitable choice of logical system). So I think Mozibur has a point...otherwise you’re just doing math.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, I have no problem with Math (personally, I much prefer it to Physics). It’s just that once you float all the way out to logical possibility it’s hard to see what makes these constants “of nature”.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I’m curious what you mean by “mereology protests against conceptualization of everything as a bag of points”. I think “points” are quite common in mereology, and how parts are typically conceived. (Classical mereology is modeled by Boolean algebras with no bottom element and, even assuming infinite descent/a non-well-founded parthood relation, each element is “point-like”.) Maybe you have in mind something like mereotopology, which takes regions as basic?

Comment: @Dennis: Lesnieski actually envisaged mereology as a competing with set theory as a foundational theory, so the parthood relationship isn't reducible to the membership relationship, it's an entirely separate theory. Though of course people have tried to model mereology as you've indicated with set theory.

Comment: parthood corresponds to inclusion from an algebraic perspective, not membership. (People have also produced merelogical reductions of Set Theory like David Lewis’s _Parts of Classes_, but a primitive Singleton operation is still needed.) I’m aware of the nominalist origins, I was just curious what it had to do with eliminating points, or what you meant by that.

Comment: @Dennis: sure - however inclusion is a derived concept unlike membership which is axiomatic, and that's what I'm driving at; if you're interested in seeing what a theory looks like that conceptualises points differently, have a look at topos theory where points have more structure than being just a mere point; to my mind that mereology emphasises parthood over membership is analogous.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to our physical theories and reality.  Either they are ways for us to discover reality or they only model reality. The answer to whether constants in these theories are irrational or rational numbers depends on which view one takes regarding the relationship between physical theories and reality.

Belief in a Theory of Everything that can be discovered about reality would assume that the constants are discovered and that they are real.  Although we may not know their exact values we may as well assume that they are irrational numbers because there are uncountably many of these and only countably many rationals. Even if we discover that the constants are changing, they are more likely irrational numbers for the same reason.

One of the goals of science would be to find exactly what the values of those constants are.  Attempting to find more precise values for these constants would challenge the technology used to make measurements.  It would be like finding the next largest prime number.

In contrast assume there does not exist a Theory of Everything.  What can one say then?  Then our physical theories are only models that approximate reality.  The constants are only useful in our models which are trained on data that we collect.  We don’t want to fit that data too tightly or we will not be able to make good predictions using the model on other data.  If that is true, then these constants are all rational numbers based on how precisely we make our measurements and how tightly we fit the training data.  We can only make those measurements to a finite number of decimal places.  Hence they would be only rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on deficient knowledge of contemporary metrology. As can be read in the site of the Bureau International des Poids and Mesures [1], the units of time (second) and length (metre) are currently **defined** such that:

- the ground state hyperfine splitting frequency of the caesium 133 atom is **exactly** 9 192 631 770 hertz ([hertz] = [1 / second]),
- the speed of light in vacuum c is **exactly** 299 792 458 metre per second.

Moreover, in the revised International System of Units (SI) expected to come into force on 20 May 2019 [2], the units of mass (kilogram) and electric charge (coulomb) will be redefined such that [3]:

- the Planck constant h is **exactly** 6.626 070 15 x 10^(–34) joule second,
- the elementary charge e is **exactly** 1.602 176 634 x 10^(–19) coulomb.

A consequence of this redefinition will be that the vacuum permeability or magnetic constant mu_0 will no longer be exactly 4 x pi x 10^(-7) H/m. So, the actual case is that a physical constant will no longer be trascendental.

**References**

[1] https://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/

[2] https://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/rev-si/

[3] http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1681-7575/aa950a/pdf